# Create vs. Generate vs. Make

Tags: word-usage, difference

I developed a software application, in which the user can create a video using some slides. What is the proper word for a button to create such a video:

- Create Video
- Generate Video
- Make Video

What is their difference?

Comment: Any of the three will do. I would go for "Generate video" as the software will generate a video from the slides. All means pretty much the same thing. I would also like to suggest "Compile Video/Slides."

Comment: With button labels (as with newspaper headlines) the need to conserve space often guides the choices one makes; the context also tends to eliminate nuance. In the context of a video software program, there is no difference in the meaning of these labels: "Pressing this button will start the process that produces a video file."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are some slight differences in how these three words are used. For example, you don't *generate* a cake.

*Create* means to make something from nothing, or to make something using a lot of creativity. A chef might *create* a new dish, but after it's been created, he might find himself *making* it every night.

*Generate* can mean produce something through a series of step prescribed by an algorithm, so it's a pretty safe word for anything built by software.

A button that said <kbd>**Generate Video**</kbd> might be emphasizing that the software will now make the video as was set up by the user, while a button that said <kbd>**Create Video**</kbd> might emphasize that the user is about to put the finishing touches on her creation. Yet <kbd>**Make Video**</kbd> is a viable option, too. One might argue that *make* is the simplest word of the three, and it might therefore be apt for software that might be used by children.

Comment: Just a note that '*making* a video' has overtones of production - lights, camera, props, etc.